# Resource referenced in user control does not appear when user control is referenced in another assembly

Tags: wpf, image, assemblies, sharing

I have 3 assemblies:

Number 1- ResourceAssembly which contains a subfolder Images with 1 image in it (build action = resource).  Within that subfolder is a ResourceDictionary with build action set to resource.  The resource dictionary contains the following-

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="BluePlus_48x48_72" UriSource="112_Plus_Blue_48x48_72.png"/>
```

Number 2 - A wpf control assembly with a single usercontrol called UserControl1.  Within that usercontrol's resources, I am loading the resource dictionary from assembly 1 and using the image in it.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ResourcesAssembly;component/Images/ImagesDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

<Image Source="{DynamicResource BluePlus_48x48_72}" Height="48" Width="48"/>
```

The image appears correctly.

Number 3 - The main application assembly.  Within the MainWindow.xaml, I reference the Project1 assembly and insert a UserControl1.

```
xmlns:p1="clr-namespace:Project1;assembly=Project1"
<p1:UserControl1 Height="60" Width="60"/>
```

However, the image does not appear.  There are no compile-time errors nor any errors ouput to the Output window at runtime.  I am at a loss as to why the image isn't appearring.  Any thought?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to also add a reference to the "ResourceAssembly" project in your main application.  Or at least have the "ResourceAssembly.dll" in the same folder as your main application's executable.

Comment: It boiled down to moving the ResourceAssembly.dll assembly into the application directory as stated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the resource reference like below.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourAssembly.Name;component/Images/ImagesDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

<Image Source="{StaticResource BluePlus_48x48_72}" Height="48" Width="48"/>
```

Note: Also, don't forgot the / in `Source="/` .

HTH